# Delete data in Access table greater than specific date-time

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I wish to have a query (that I'll run through an Excel Macro) that will delete data in an Access table if the Order Date is greater than a specific Date-Time (that will be defined as a variable from Excel.

In basic terms, I want to know how I can do the following:

```
Delete *
FROM Detailed
WHERE Detailed.[Order Date]>'20/04/2017 23:57:19' ;
```

but when I run this query it comes up with Data Type Mismatch.

What format do I need this date to be in for it to work? And how can I transfer this from an Excel stored variable into the SQL Query?

This is the bit of the Macro I am using currently:

```
acApp.DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM [OrdersDetailed] WHERE Month([OrderDate])=Month(Date()) And Year([OrderDate])=Year(Date())"
```

Thanks,

Benji

Comment: I would personally use ADO, make the DB connection and then send the sql command that you want. I also make a point to never use Access, but that's not always an option.

Comment: ^^ At the moment the question is confusing. If it is about having an Excel macro, you should start some effort setting up an `ADODB,Connection` and asking it to `.Execute` your query, then show your attempt and we will help you take it to good end. If the question is about the correct query to do that, rephrase your question and dont mention Excel macros and other stuff..

Comment: Try enclosing the date in hashes e.g. `WHERE Detailed.[Order Date]>#20/04/2017 23:57:19#;`

Comment: Thank you xidgel, that is what I needed. Had to also deal with the date being in the wrong US format, but got there in the end using the above.

A. S. H. the post had two parts really, and I didn't want to be too uninformative as that may have prompted the wrong answer. xidgel has answered the part about how to get the Date Time into the Query, and I have had to look elsewhere to find out how to put an excel variable into the query:

        acApp.DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM [OrdersDetailed] WHERE [OrderDate]>=#" & LastOrderDate & "#"